# How to change the "creator" of a Flow in Power-Automate and of a Team in MS Teams?

Tags: permissions, flow, power-automate, microsoft-teams, roles

Basically these are two questions, but they belong to each other.

**First question:**
We've made the experience, that a creator of a team (the one, who created it) is still the owner of a team when we clone the team via the graph api: https://docs.microsoft.com/de-de/graph/api/team-clone?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http without specifying to clone the members. All other members don't get cloned. Is it possible to change this (undocumented) creator role afterwards?

**Second question:**
Is it possible to change the creator of a PowerAutomate-Flow? The bin-icon ist grey and can't be clicked, even if all connections of the creator are changed to connections of other people:
[image: owners in Power Automate]
A potential way could be to export the flow and import it in another users profile again.
We didn't test this way right now.
Are there other ways to ensure continuous function of the flow, even if the creator would leave the company and the user account gets deleted?

Thanks for any hint!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my knowledge there is no way to directly change the original owner of power automate currently.

if you want to make another owner (Another Microsoft Flow account) the original owner of your flow, you could consider take a try to export your flow as a Package and then import the flow package into another user Microsoft Flow account.

For team- After cloning you can change the owner of gropu belonging to team through Microsoft  admin center.

refer below article for more details
[Change Owner of Microsoft Team](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/skypehybridguy/microsoft-teams-help-the-team-owner-left-the-company-and-we-dont-know-what-to-do)

Comment: Please as answer if you are satified with answer it will help other